# ExtJs 5 bind store to cell editor in grid

Tags: mvvm, extjs5, javascript-databinding

I'm trying to bind store to combobox editor in grid. My view is subclass of grid with cellediting plugin. I'm trying to bind at least static store with yes/no option. I tried many options and nothing worked.

Grid class:

```
Ext.define('App.view.school.room.RoomGrid', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.school-room-grid',

controller: 'school-room-grid',

requires: [
    'App.view.school.room.RoomGridController',
    'App.view.school.room.RoomGridViewModel',
    'Ext.button.Button',
    'Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing',
    'Ext.grid.Panel',
    'Ext.picker.Color',
    'Ext.toolbar.Paging',
    'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar'
],

reference: 'roomGrid',

viewModel: {
    type: 'room'
},

bind: {
    store: '{rooms}',
    title: '{currentRoom.name}'
},

border: false,
itemId: 'testGrid',
glyph: 0xf0ce,
forceFit: true,
plugins: [
    {
        ptype: 'cellediting',
        pluginId: 'editing'
    }
],
header: {
    title: 'Title',
    padding: '4 9 4 9'
},
columns: [
   //...
    {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'general',
        text: 'SomeColumnYesNo',
        editor:{
            xtype: 'combobox',
            bind: {
                value:'{currentRoom.general}',
                store:'{yesnoCombo}' //not working
            },
            displayField : 'name',
            valueField : 'id',
            selectOnFocus: true
        }
    }
],
buttons: [
    {
        itemId: 'addButton',
        xtype: 'button',
        width: 70,
        scale: 'small',
        text: 'Dodaj',
        glyph: 0xf067
    },
    {
        itemId: 'printButton',
        xtype: 'button',
        width: 70,
        scale: 'small',
        text: 'Drukuj',
        glyph: 0xf02f
    },
    {
        xtype: 'tbfill'
    },
    {
        itemId: 'rejectButton',
        xtype: 'button',
        width: 22,
        scale: 'small',
        text: 'Anuluj',
        glyph: 0xf021,
        bind: {
            disabled: '{!storeDirty}'
        }
    },
    {
        itemId: 'saveButton',
        xtype: 'button',
        width: 22,
        scale: 'small',
        text: 'Zapisz',
        glyph: 0xf00c,
        bind: {
            disabled: '{!storeDirty}'
        }
    }
],

initComponent: function () {

    me.callParent(arguments);
},
```

});

ViewModel class:

```
Ext.define('App.view.school.room.RoomGridViewModel', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
alias: 'viewmodel.room',

requires: [
    'App.store.RoomStore',
    'App.store.BuildingStore',
    'App.store.TeacherStore',
    'App.store.local.YesNoStore'
],

stores: {
    //...
    yesnoCombo:{
        type:'local.yesnostore'
    }
},

data: {
    currentRoom: null
}
```

});

ViewController class:

```
Ext.define('App.view.school.room.RoomGridController', {
extend: 'Deft.mvc.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.school-room-grid',

requires: [
    'App.view.school.room.RoomGridViewModel'
],

inject: [
    'viewContext'
],

bind: {
    currentRoom: '{currentRoom}',
    store: '{rooms}'
},

config: {
    currentRoom: null,

    /** @type App.store.RoomStore */
    roomStore: null,
    /** @type App.context.ViewContext */
    viewContext: null
},

control: {
    '#': {
        boxready: 'onBoxReady',
        select: 'onSelect'
    },
    '#addButton': {
        click: 'onAddButtonClick'
    },
    '#rejectButton': {
        click: 'onRejectButtonClick'
    },
    '#saveButton': {
        click: 'onSaveButtonClick'
    }
},

onStoreLoading: function () {
    Deft.Logger.info(this.$className + '.onStoreLoading');
    var me = this;
    me.getView().setLoading(true);
},

onStoreLoaded: function () {
    Deft.Logger.info(this.$className + '.onStoreLoaded');
    var me = this;
    me.getView().setLoading(false);
},
//...
}
```

static store:

```
Ext.define('Perykles.store.local.YesNoStore', {
extend:'Ext.data.Store',
fields: ['id', 'name'],
autoLoad:false,
alias: 'store.local.yesnostore',
data : [
    {"id":"true", "name":"Tak"},
    {"id":"false", "name":"Nie"}
]
});
```

When I click on column binded to store to edit value instead of showing yes/no option in combobox i receive following error:

```
[E] Cannot modify ext-empty-store 
Object 
console.trace()
Uncaught Error: Cannot modify ext-empty-store
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Throw your full code into a jsfiddle or sencha fiddle so I can debug it if you can.  Here's a working example of binding https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/bg6

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? I have the same issue...

Comment: Unfortunately no, happily, we are using Deft MVC library and we've found a workaround.